# requested css file path with encrypted string

Tags: http

After viewing source code of some websites

I notice that the path of file postfix with encrypted string

What's it usage?

```
<link href="/assets/css/fonts.css?201f2952086aa892d8e1902046989c98b3bda218" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is used to make sure that the client is caching the correct version of this resource